# Selecting xpath using a variable in selenium 2

Tags: selenium2, python

I am doing a selenium automation where I want to pass the variable into the XPath and select the element.

The xpath which I am trying looks like:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'SEM W880 Black')]")
```

I would like to pass the text `SEM W880 Black` as a variable to the XPath. How can I do it using python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, this appears to be a Python question rather than a QA question.  The answer to the Python question is something like,

```
x = 'SEM W880 Black'
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'" + x + "')]")
```

If I misunderstood you, please update the question.

Comment: This is neat answer,I have not thought we can write in python. I thought there could be a function in the selenium where I can pass the variable as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium IDE, you can do this: 
Declaration in Selenium IDE:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeExpression</td>
    <td>SEM W880 Black</td>
    <td>name_of_your_variable</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//a[contains(text(),'${name_of_your_variable}')]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Simply put, you can store the variable and use it between simple quotes. 

Please take note that the target field, in Selenium IDE is without any kind of quotes.

Comment: This does not really answer the OP's question, which is asking for the way to pass the variable using Python.